# Interesting, but weird Google behavior on redirected URLs, if redirect targets are disallowed for crawling

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, robots.txt

There are two sites: `a.example` and `b.example`.

- URLs `a.example/cat` were allowed for crawling at a.example/robots.txt.
- URLs `a.example/cat/page` were disallowed for crawling at a.example/robots.txt.

Then

`a.example/cat` and `a.example/cat/page` were moved to `b.example` with 301 redirect. They become

- `b.example/cat` (allowed for crawling at b.example/robots.txt),
- `b.example/cat/page` (disallowed for crawling at b.example/robots.txt)

Robots.txt at `a.example` has since redirection no allow/disallow rules.

**The problem**: URLs `a.example/cat/page` are listed in the Search Console as `indexed, but disallowed for crawling`, despite all sitemaps and robots.txt are already processed.

**My suspicion**: if Googlebot goes for 301-redirect and gets as target an URL, disallowed for crawling, it can process nor source neither target URL. If so, it is weird. Correct behavior would be to drop from GSC any infos about source URL.

Has anybody an idea, how to remove `a.example/cat/page` from the list `indexed, but disallowed for crawling`?

Comment: What does `/cat` have to do with it?   I don't think it changes your question at all if the parent directory is allowed or disallowed via robots.txt?

Comment: Why would the "correct" behavior be to drop all info about a URL from Google Search Console?   I don't think I've ever seen Google completely forget about URLs.

Comment: `/cat` is mentioned for the completenes of the view. With `correct` i mean: i expect that eventual warnings, like `indexed, but blocked for crawling` are dropped if an url is anyhow permanently away: 301 (not 302), 404, 410.

Comment: Seems the expected behaviour. The URL is disallowed from crawling, but nothing is stopping it from being indexed. As it is not crawled Google will have little information about it in the index. Just text associated with links to it. See Important in... https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Comment: @TonyMcCreath but the source urls is no longer disallowed! This is what makes me suspect.

Comment: I suspect that Google is reporting it is disallowed because the URL it redirects to is disallowed.  I'm not sure that there is anything going on here other than confusing messaging in Google Search Console.